# File Replication/Synchronization between multiple sites using BitTorrent

Tags: synchronization, replication, distributed, p2p, bittorrent

I need to build a distributed system which relies on replication of large files between the sites.

I thought of using p2p technology like bittorrent to save on bandwidth, and increase reliability.

Am I terribly wrong?

Have anyone ever architected such a solution?

What libraries do you recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A new promising solution from the developers of BitTorrent: [BitTorrent Sync](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html).

It has the following features:

- Unlimited and free!
- Currently supports Windows, Mac and Linux. Mobile platforms are in the works.
- Specifically designed to handle large files.
- Private and secure: all traffic is encrypted.
- Peer discovery protocols.
- Supports traffic relay for disconnected nodes.

Comment: BitTorrent Sync is now Resilio Sync

Answer (score 3):

I just found this open-source project from Twitter which hits the nail perfectly:

### https://github.com/lg/murder

From the docs:

> **Murder** is a method of using Bittorrent to distribute files to a large amount of servers within a production environment. This allows for scaleable and fast deploys in environments of hundreds to tens of thousands of servers where centralized distribution systems wouldn't otherwise function. A "Murder" is normally used to refer to a flock of crows, which in this case applies to a bunch of servers doing something.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 2 sites, then p2p is better solution IMHO.

Just install [rtorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/), [deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/) or any other high-performance torrent client at every site. Than you can distribute only .torrent files with scp/sftp and enjoy.

In order to secure the content from third party torrent clients, set the private flag when producing the .torrent file and use your own tracker. [opentracker](http://erdgeist.org/arts/software/opentracker/) is a good choice.

One more hint: if your torrent client supports [super seeding mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-seeding) (aka [BEP-16](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0016.html) or initial seeding), enable it. It'll help distribute the content with minimum duplication between nodes.